# FastAPI Pagination with Redis

Tags: python, redis, pagination, fastapi

Currently I have some cached data in a Redis cluster and the data is being served over an endpoint developed by FastAPI.

Below is an example:

```
key_001: [value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4]
```

There is another service that updates this data in real-time. For example this service and delete an existing value or insert a new value into the list.

```
key_001: [value_1, value_2, value_10]
```

The FastAPI endpoint will read this data and paginate it according to the given parameters. For example, the `page = 1` and the `size = 1`.

What if the next moment, the data changes to a new list? With the same page and size, the data is different? How do I update the API so that it will serve the new content?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want your page to have real-time updates the options are to use event based or polling based updates of your data. Polling is purely client side and fairly simple to implement, but is less efficient and updates with lag. Event based updates would require server and client implementing something like websockets, which would be more responsive, but increases code complexity.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Let me give it a try!